# How does the Bitcoin forex work?

Tags: trading, economic-theory, value

Does it work differently in relation to a regular forex because of its underlying technology?

How can the market calculate its value?

Comment: Hi Mark Thompson, welcome to Quant.SE! I'll have to close this question for three reasons. First of all, ask one question at a time. Second, I believe this fits better on the Bitcoin Stack. Third, I believe this is too basic for both stacks. On the Bitcoin exchanges, the protocol plays no role and price is determined by supply and demand.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a generalistic question about a market or marketplace. It's not specific to Bitcoin. And this question has been attracting low quality answers and spam.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's all the same. Well, maybe there are some very small differences, but in general it's the same as forex. I would say that the cryptocurrency is much more unstable, and this is why I prefer trading CFDs on [Investous broker](https://www.investous.com/). I am much better in that area, and it's much easier for me to analyze this market. However, it has the same thing at base, so, if you are already good in one area, you will be successful in the other one too.  I would suggest reading more information about that on the internet, there is a lot of information available on that topic

Comment: No is a good answer if you can back it up, but then you kind of weakened it by referring to small differences.  To back up your NO answer, you could list all the differences you know about (writing them off as "small") and hypothesize some that might be big enough to count (but don't exist, as far as you know). This would demonstrate your awareness of the issues involved and add credibility to your answer.